# django: render versus render_to_response and its relation to csrf_token

Tags: django, django-csrf

I have usually been using render_to_response for my view functions in django.

However, recently, I have been trying to use more of the render method (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) which as I understand here from the docs, automatically includes 'context_instance' if none is provided.

How does this optional context_instance argument work in relation to crsf_token? Do I have to explicitly send in a template variable such as "csrf(request)", using something like

```
template_vars.update(csrf(request))
```

I am asking about this because I am getting an inexplicable

```
"Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request Aborted".
```

Even though I have the csrf middleware enabled in my settings.py and in my template, form, a {% csrf_token %} templatetag call.

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to add `django.core.context_processors.csrf` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`?

Comment: nope. unfortunately. I have that already included in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS